# Tensorflow: stack (m, n, k, p) and (m, n, 1, p) tensors along the axis=2

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have to stack (m, n, k, p) and (m, n, 1, p) tensors along the axis=2.

`tf.pack` can only manage tensors of the same shape.

I've tried to use `tf.unpack` but it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I believe you are trying to do is called [tf.concat](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#concat):

```
a = tf.zeros([3,4,10,5])
b = tf.zeros([3,4,1,5])
c = tf.concat(2, [a,b])

c.get_shape()
Out: TensorShape([Dimension(3), Dimension(4), Dimension(11), Dimension(5)])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know this op.

Comment: You can [accept a helpful answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking a grey tick next to it.